# Why do images get formed only on specific positions in ray diagrams?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

[image]

For example, why in this case does the image get formed at only $2F$ and not at $X$, if the only condition for formation of the image is that $2$ light rays should converge at a point?

Comment: Forget about the number, "2." An image is formed when the optic reflects and/or refracts _all_ of the light rays emanating from _each point_ on the subject plane to the corresponding point in the image plane.

Comment: Ahhhh I get it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> . . . if the only condition for formation of image is that 2 light
> rays should converge at a point.

is not true.

Here is your diagram with a few more rays added and sorry for them not being straight).

[image].

The red rays leave the bottom of the object $B$ along a normal to the mirror and are reflected back to cross in phase with one another at $B’$.
All the red rays and many more in between are responsible for the formation of the image of the bottom of the object.

The green rays, including two that you have drawn and all the others i between, form the top of the object all cross and arrive in phase at the top of the image $A’$.

Thus I hope that I have shown you that it is all rays which start from a position on the object which after reflection from the mirror a cross in phase which are responsible for the formation of the image of the object.

Comment: I have read at a lot of places that when 2 light rays coming from an object intersect, the form an image. Is this statement false?

Comment: @Yuvraj Your statement is correct but not complete.  The rays you normally meet are *construction or predictable rays* to help identify the location of the image as in your diagram but there are many others rays which form the image.

Answer (score 1):

Light rays coming from a point on the object spread out. There are many points in an object. Each one is a source of spreading light rays. That would be a mess to draw, so ray diagrams just show one or two. You are supposed to know that all the other points work much like the examples shown in the diagram. You can see how from @Farcher's diagram how it quickly gets hard to see what is going on.

The remarkable thing about a lens or mirror is that they take light rays spreading out from a point and redirect them so they converge to a point. They do this for light from all the points in an object. The set of points where light converges is called the image.

The converging rays pass through the image point and keep going. After passing through, light spreads out from an image point just like it does from an object point. This is why an image looks like an object. Your eye gets the same light from each.

So the thing you missed at X is that you are looking at the place where a ray spreading out from the object crosses a ray heading toward a convergence point from the mirror.

The ray diagram only shows two rays from the tip of the arrow. This is because many times you want to find where the image is and how big it is. Two rays is the minimum number needed to find where all the rays from the tip cross. Here you see how it gets confusing if very few rays are drawn. But once you get used to ray diagrams, just a few rays is enough.